# __get__ Attribute of function in Python

Tags: python, function, get

I created a function as:

```
>>> def sum(a,b):
...     return a+b
... 
>>> sum.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x18a85f0>
>>> sum.__get__("ghj")
<bound method ?.sum of 'ghj'>

    >>> dir(sum)
    ['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '***__get__***', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
    >>>
```

I want to know about practical use of __get__ with a function. I will be thankful if anyone would explain a practical use of each attribute with function.

Comment: It's a data descriptor method of a function object, an integral part of Python's [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=descriptors).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in Python, everything is object (even classes and functions!)
And as objects, all functions have a `__get__` method.

`__get__` is useful especially for implementing [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#id1):

```
class Celsius:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner): return 9 * (instance.fahrenheit + 32) / 5
    def __set__(self, instance, value): instance.fahrenheit = 32 + 5 * value / 9

class Temperature:
    def __init__(self, initial_f): self.fahrenheit = initial_f
    celsius = Celsius()

t = Temperature(212)
print(t.celsius)
t.celsius = 0
print(t.fahrenheit)
```

Output:

```
100.0
32.0
```